# Use a received file name as a parameter for an exe in a batch file

Tags: xml, loops, batch-file, base64

I have a lot of xml-files in different subdirectories and want to encode the xml-files to base64 and save every encoded blob in a txt. I use the Windows .NET Framework Base64 Converter to encode one single file with the command:
base64Converter.exe /e myinputfile.xml mybase64outputfile.txt

This works for one single file but I have to encode 148 files. So I want to do this with a batch file. I'm new to writing batches and need some help.

What I figured out by now:

```
FOR /r %%d IN (*.xml) DO (

SET XML=%%d

echo %XML%

)

FOR /r %%r IN (*.xml) DO (

START "" "Patch to base64Converter.exe" /e %XML% out.txt

)

PAUSE
```

I want to write the filenames from the first loop to a variable and process this variable to the base64Converter.exe. But my var 'XML' stores the absolute path. What can I do to provide just the filename in the right directory to base64Converter.exe? Or is there a syntax error with the brackets? Is it also possible to overwrite my xml files and to save the base64 blob right in the file?

My output:

```
C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\mydirectory>(START "" "c:\Users\myUser\Desktop\mydirectory\b64c.exe" /e C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\mydirectory\MyData\ViewBase\panelManager.LayoutStream.xml out.txt )
```

I appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: If you read the very bottom section of the help file for the `FOR` command you will see what you need to modify the FOR variable.

Comment: Which help file do you mean?

Comment: Pretty much any command you use at a cmd prompt including any third party utilities have some form of a help file you can access.  For the most part this is done by typing the command name followed by a forward slash and a question mark: `FOR /?`

Comment: If you are lazy. [Microsoft]( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx) and [SS64 NT A-Z](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: Okay so I found the parameters in the documentation. And use SET XML=%%~fd to get the full path of the xml files, to store it in a variable and to give it as a first parameter to the base64Converter.exe. What is a good approach to write the encoded blob in a new file (second parameter)? The better solution would be to overwrite the xmls. Is this possible?

Comment: You don't need to set it to another variable.  Just use the for variable directly with your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update*

I figured it out and wrote a batch file for my purpose.

```
FOR /R %%d IN (*.xml) DO (

REM create an empty txt with the same filename
echo. 2>%%~pd%%~nd.txt

REM Execute b64c.exe with parameters
START "" /B "%PATH%\b64c.exe" /e "%%~fd" "%%~pd%%~nd.txt"

)
```

I used the parameter of the FOR loop to get the full path and pass them to the base64Converter.

Thanks for your tips!